# Is it possible to train the transformer model in google colab? (Not gpt2)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

i understand that gpt2 is based on the transformer architecture but where is the source code, there are limited resources and no tutorial on how to write one..
I am new to NLP and also if i had to generate novels, would training the transformer on multiple novels help or  one?

Comment: I believe this is the source code: https://github.com/openai/gpt-2

Comment: i am not looking for gpt2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to train GPT and other trasnformers is by using the library https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers. They also have a course that can help you to familiarize with the topic: https://huggingface.co/course/

Yes, transformer models, if they are not too large, can be trained on Colab.

And yes, GPT-like models can be trained to generate novels, but only short ones (like several paragraphs), because almost all such models can work only with texts of limited length.

Comment: thanks, so if i understand correctly, gpt is a model which adopts the transformer architecture right? then why is there no codes like in RNN or LSTM

Comment: @Vortekus GPT is a multi-layer decoder-only Transformer, it doesn't have LSTM or RNN layers because it understands language using Attention mechanism and Positional Embeddings.

Comment: If you want source code for GPT, see https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/src/transformers/models/gpt2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and it would be better if you use GPU for training. make sure modify `num_train_epochs`,  `per_device_train_batch_size` and `per_gpu_train_batch_size` features in TrainingArguments to prevent runtime from crashing! >> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory

most of the time it will use the whole GPU and RAM and the notebook would crash!